# Linux Ubuntu problem: recovery menu and choice

Tags: boot, grub2

I tried to install a new version of R on a conda environment. The terminal then warned me that I did not have sufficient memory on my disk and I therefore canceled the installation.

After working for 10 minutes on my version of R (Rstudio to be precise) it crashed (impossible to save my scripts) then after closing the application the computer displayed R/Rstudio as uninstalled.

Thinking of a basic error, I tried to restart my PC but it systematically takes me to a black screen with a flashing white dash. I tried to solve the problem without going through the recovery menu but nothing seems to solve it.

So I come to you to find out if any of the options offered by the recovery menu seem relevant to you?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Getting that far suggests that you are getting through the BIOS start-up OK, but the operating system is failing to start. Given the previous warning, it is likely that your disk is full. Some writing to disk is needed during boot, so that will be why it isn't coming up. Boot from a liveCD or USB stick. That will give you access to the disk and you can look around for things to delete, after which it should boot correctly and you can maybe do a clean-up on the partial R upgrade.